# jquery modal popup guidance needed. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, modal-dialog

I'm creating a website and on one page of the site (it's .php) I have two links. The first reads register and the next reads login.  I am using jquery to create a popup and which form pops up depend on the link clicked. (I am trying to do this but not able to).  I have 2 files in total (logReg.php) and (popup.css).

When I click on login the login form pops up as expected, but when i click on register nothing pops up.  And if I reverse these that if I put the jquery code for register first then... the register box pops up but the login doesn't.  I have read the `click()` function's jquery API but it seems to me i'm doing everything right but obviously not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. BTW This code is not 100% mine I modified the code that I found for a single popup window.

Content of logReg.php

```
<html>
     <head>
          <!-- Typical stuff here. link to the popup.css & jquery.js -->
          <title>MyPage</title>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("a.login-window").click(function () {

                         //Getting the variable's value from a link
                         var loginBox = $(this).attr("href");

                         //fade in the popup
                         $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

                         //set the center alignment padding
                         var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2;
                         var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2;

                         $(loginBox).css({
                              'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
                              'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
                         });

                         //Add the mask to body
                         $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
                         $('mask').fadeIn(300);
                         return false;
                    });

                    //When clicking on the button close the pop closed
                    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() {
                         $('#mask, .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function() {
                              $('#mask').remove();
                         });
                         return false;
                    });

                    $("a.register-window").click(function () {

                         //Getting the variable's value from a link
                         var registerBox = $(this).attr("href");

                         //fade in the popup
                         $(registerBox).fadeIn(300);

                         //set the center alignment padding
                         var popMargTop = ($(registerBox).height() + 24) / 2;
                         var popMargLeft = ($(registerBox).width() + 24) / 2;

                         $(registerBox).css({
                              'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
                              'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
                         });

                         //Add the mask to body
                         $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
                         $('mask').fadeIn(300);
                         return false;
                    });

                    //When clicking on the button close the pop closed
                    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() {
                         $('#mask, .register-popup').fadeOut(300, function() {
                              $('#mask').remove();
                         });
                         return false;
                    });
               });
          </script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div id="links>
               <a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a>
               <a href="#register-box" class="register-window">Register</a>
          </div>
          <div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
               <form method="post" class="signin" action="">
                    <!-- All form stuff here -->
               </form>
          </div>
          <div id="#register-box" class="register-popup">
               <form method="post" class="signin" action="">
                    <!-- All form stuff here -->
               </form>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I noticed you have a # id on your register-box div, but not on your login-box div, could this be causing the issue

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos I now updated to jquery 1.9 and my problem has been fixed.  I followed mikakun's advice.

IanO.S. that was a typo but no it wasn't causing the problem because in my code it wasn't there... I didn't copy and paste it here I retyped the code line by line so that I can catch any mistake I might have made while typing lol instead I made a mistake here.  But yeah good eye that # shouldn't of been there. Thanks for the input but the problem has been solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first don't use .live, upgrade jquery and use

  ```
  $(document.body).on({event:function(){},...},"selector"
  ```
- second don't use append, use

  ```
  $('<div../>').appendTo($(document.body));
  ```

(i believe your bug comes from second)

also you could make a plugin of your open box code, then you bind the two at once using.on

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestions fixed my problem.  This might be sort of a lame questions but what IDE do you use to develop? What IDE is javascript friendly? I'm using netbeans right now I mean it gets the job done but I was hoping maybe something better.  I"m new to web development.

Comment: @PAujla03 using komodo edit free version, can be buggy & takes lots of ram & needs a sudo launch on ubuntu to update/upgrade but provides great auto-complete & error checking warning; also lots of configuration options to personalize to your need + (obviously) firebug & google (& stackoverflow) for debugging

Answer (score 1):

For starters you are missing a double quote on this line:

`<div id="links>`

change to

`<div id="links">`

That should get your links fixed.

Then you should do what mikakun said about upgrading jquery and using `.on` as it is best to stay current.